# LibreOffice: The program crashes when we call the FrameLoader.loadComponentFromURL method

Tags: c#, libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno

We are usingthe UNO library to edit template in LibreOffice.
The existing implementation was developed using LibreOffice 6.4.4. With this version this worked without any problems. Likewise with version 7.0.0. With version 7.1.7 the problem described could be reproduced. The assumption is that this problem exists as of version 7.1.0.

```
var vDoc = _config.FrameLoader.loadComponentFromURL(urlTemplate, "_top", 0, null);
_config.UpdateFrame(this.Info, vDoc);
```

The following points must be observed when using or checking the current LibreOffice version (currently 7.2.4 x86)

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this is not a question, this is a bug report. We will not be able to help you here, the error should be reported to [**Bugzilla**](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=LibreOffice).

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN. I have reported it to Bugzilla.